# Unable to use jstring as an argument inside native code

Tags: c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, artoolkit

I need to use `const char *` inside my native code so , I took the argument from java side as `jstring` and use the following statements

```
JNIEXPORT int JNICALL JNIFUNCTION_DEMO(AddMarkerAndModel(JNIEnv* env, jobject object, jstring modelfileString , jstring marker_config_string)) {

    int free_marker_space_index=-1;

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_MODELS; i++) {
        if (models[i].not_null==false) {
            free_marker_space_index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(free_marker_space_index==-1){
        //means no space for marker left
        return free_marker_space_index;
    }
    const char *marker_config = env->GetStringUTFChars( marker_config_string, NULL);
    LOGE("[KARTIK]marker_config is : %s",marker_config);

    models[free_marker_space_index].patternID = arwAddMarker(marker_config);


    arwSetMarkerOptionBool(models[free_marker_space_index].patternID, ARW_MARKER_OPTION_SQUARE_USE_CONT_POSE_ESTIMATION, false);
    arwSetMarkerOptionBool(models[free_marker_space_index].patternID, ARW_MARKER_OPTION_FILTERED, true);

    const char *modelfile = env->GetStringUTFChars( modelfileString, NULL);
    LOGE("[KARTIK]modelFile is : %s",modelfile);
    models[free_marker_space_index].obj = glmReadOBJ2(modelfile, 0, 0); // context 0, don't read textures yet.
    if (!models[free_marker_space_index].obj) {
        LOGE("Error loading model from file '%s'.", modelfile);
        exit(-1);
    }
//  LOGV("just checking this function..no error..don't worry");
    //printf("just checking this function..no error..don't worry");
    glmScale(models[free_marker_space_index].obj, 0.035f);
    //glmRotate(models[0].obj, 3.14159f / 2.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glmCreateArrays(models[free_marker_space_index].obj, GLM_SMOOTH | GLM_MATERIAL | GLM_TEXTURE);
    models[free_marker_space_index].visible = false;
    models[free_marker_space_index].not_null=true;

    //LOGV("ReleaseStringUTFChars");
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(modelfileString, modelfile);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(marker_config_string, marker_config);    


    return free_marker_space_index;
}
```

this function says unable to read mtl file whose code is in glm.c..a part of it is below ...have a look at ReadOBJ and ReadMTL functions

```
#include <Eden/glm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>             // USHRT_MAX
#include <Eden/EdenMath.h>      // M_PI, sqrtf(), acosf(), asinf(), fabsf()
#ifndef EDEN_OPENGLES
#  define DISABLE_GL_STATE_CACHE
#endif
#include "glStateCache.h"
#ifndef GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP
#  define GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP 0x8191
#endif

#define glmDefaultGroupName "default"
#define T(x) (model->triangles[(x)])

/* _GLMnode: general purpose node, used by glmVertexNormals() to build a
    linked list of triangles containing a particular vertex. */
typedef struct _GLMnode {
    GLuint          index;      // Which triangle this node is tracking.
    GLuint          indexindex; // Which of the points in this triangle this node is tracking.
    GLboolean       averaged;
    struct _GLMnode* next;      // The next node in the list, or NULL if this node is the tail.
} GLMnode;

/* _GLMnode: general purpose node, used by glmDrawArrays() to build a
 linked list of triangles containing a particular vertex. */
typedef struct _GLMnode2 {
    GLushort          index; // Index into list of per-vertex data values. Each 3 defines a triangle.
    struct _GLMnode2* next;     // The next node in the list, or NULL if this node is the tail.
} GLMnode2;

#define glmMax(a, b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
#define glmMin(a, b) ((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))


/* glmFindMaterial: Find a material in the model */
static GLuint glmFindMaterial(GLMmodel* model, char* name)
{
    GLuint i;

    /* XXX doing a linear search on a string key'd list is pretty lame,
    but it works and is fast enough for now. */
    for (i = 0; i < model->nummaterials; i++) {
        if (!strcmp(model->materials[i].name, name))
            goto found;
    }

    /* didn't find the name, so print a warning and return the default
    material (0). */
    EDEN_LOGe("glmFindMaterial():  can't find material \"%s\".\n", name);
    i = 0;

found:
    return i;
}

/* glmDirName: return the directory given a path
 *
 * path - filesystem path
 *
 * NOTE: the return value should be free'd.
 */
static char*
glmDirName(char* path)
{
    char* dir;
    char* s;

    dir = strdup(path);

    s = strrchr(dir, '/');
    if (s)
        s[1] = '\0';    // place end of string after last separator
    else
        dir[0] = '\0';

    return dir;
}

#ifdef GLM_MATERIAL_TEXTURES
static GLboolean readTextureAndSendToGL(const int contextIndex, char *texturefilename, TEXTURE_INDEX_t *texturemap_index, char *texturemap_hasAlpha, const GLboolean flipH, const GLboolean flipV)
{
    TEXTURE_INFO_t textureInfo = {      // PRL 2003-08-06: Defaults for texturemaps.
        NULL,                           //   pointer to name will go here.
        GL_TRUE,                        //   generate mipmaps.
        0,                              //   internal format (0 = don't attempt conversion).
        GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR,        //   minification mode.
        GL_LINEAR,                      //   magnification mode.
        GL_REPEAT,                      //   wrap_s.
        GL_REPEAT,                      //   wrap_t.
        0.5,                            //   priority.
        GL_REPLACE,                     //   env_mode.
        //{0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0}             //   env_color.
    };
    static char initedSurfaces = FALSE;

    textureInfo.pathname = texturefilename;
    if (!initedSurfaces) {
        EdenSurfacesInit(1, 256); // Up to 256 textures, into 1 OpenGL context.
        initedSurfaces = TRUE;
    }
    if (!EdenSurfacesTextureLoad2(contextIndex, 1, &textureInfo, texturemap_index, texturemap_hasAlpha, flipH, flipV)) {
        EDEN_LOGe("EdenSurfacesTextureLoad() couldn't read texture file \"%s\".\n", texturefilename);
        return (FALSE);
    }
    return (TRUE);
}
#endif // GLM_MATERIAL_TEXTURES

/* glmReadMTL: read a wavefront material library file
 *
 * model - properly initialized GLMmodel structure
 * name  - name of the material library
 * contextIndex - PRL: index to the current OpenGL context (for texturing.) If you have only
 *             one OpenGL context (the most common case) set this parameter to 0.
 */
static GLboolean
glmReadMTL(GLMmodel* model, char* name, const int contextIndex, const GLboolean readTexturesNow)
{
    FILE* file;
    char* dir;
    char* filename;
    char    buf[128];
    GLuint nummaterials, i;

    dir = glmDirName(model->pathname);
    filename = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(dir) + strlen(name) + 1));
    strcpy(filename, dir);
    strcat(filename, name);
    free(dir);

    file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!file) {
        EDEN_LOGe("glmReadMTL() failed: can't open material file \"%s\".\n", filename);
        return (FALSE);
    }

    /* count the number of materials in the file */
    nummaterials = 1; // default material 0 is always defined.
    while(fscanf(file, "%s", buf) != EOF) {
        switch(buf[0]) {
        case '#':               /* comment */
            /* eat up rest of line */
            fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file);
            break;
        case 'n':               /* newmtl */
            fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file);
            nummaterials++;
            //sscanf(buf, "%s %s", buf, buf);
            break;
        default:
            /* eat up rest of line */
            fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file);
            break;
        }
    }

    rewind(file);

    model->materials = (GLMmaterial*)malloc(sizeof(GLMmaterial) * nummaterials);
    model->nummaterials = nummaterials;

    /* set the defaults for each material */
    for (i = 0; i < nummaterials; i++) {
        model->materials[i].name = NULL;
        model->materials[i].shininess = 65.0;
        model->materials[i].diffuse[0] = 0.8;
        model->materials[i].diffuse[1] = 0.8;
        model->materials[i].diffuse[2] = 0.8;
        model->materials[i].diffuse[3] = 1.0; // Opaque.
        model->materials[i].ambient[0] = 0.2;
        model->materials[i].ambient[1] = 0.2;
        model->materials[i].ambient[2] = 0.2;
        model->materials[i].ambient[3] = 1.0;
        model->materials[i].specular[0] = 0.0;
        model->materials[i].specular[1] = 0.0;
        model->materials[i].specular[2] = 0.0;
        model->materials[i].specular[3] = 1.0;
#ifdef GLM_MATERIAL_TEXTURES
        model->materials[i].texturemap = NULL;      // PRL 20030806: No texture by default.
        model->materials[i].texturemappath = NULL;
        model->materials[i].texturemap_index = (TEXTURE_INDEX_t)0;
        model->materials[i].texturemap_hasAlpha = 0;
#endif // GLM_MATERIAL_TEXTURES
        model->materials[i].illum = 2; // Is 2 the default?
    }
    model->materials[0].name = strdup("default");

    /* now, read in the data */
    nummaterials = 0;
    while(fscanf(file, "%s", buf) != EOF) {
        switch(buf[0]) {
            case '#':               /* comment */
                /* eat up rest of line */
                fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file);
                break;
            case 'n':               /* newmtl */
                fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file);
                sscanf(buf, "%s %s", buf, buf);
                nummaterials++;
                model->materials[nummaterials].name = strdup(buf);
                break;
            case 'N':
                switch (buf[1]) {
                    case 's':
                        fscanf(file, "%f", &model->materials[nummaterials].shininess);
                        /* wavefront shininess is from [0, 1000], so scale to [0, 127] for OpenGL */
                        model->materials[nummaterials].shininess /= 1000.0;
                        model->materials[nummaterials].shininess *= 128.0;
                        break;
                    default:
                        // Unsupported options:
                        // Ni = Refraction index. Values range from 1 upwards. A value of 1 will cause no refraction. A higher value implies refraction.
                        fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 'K':
                switch(buf[1]) {
                    case 'd':
                        fscanf(file, "%f %f %f",
                            &model->materials[nummaterials].diffuse[0],
                            &model->materials[nummaterials].diffuse[1],
                            &model->materials[nummaterials].diffuse[2]);
                        break;
                    case 's':
                        fscanf(file, "%f %f %f",
                            &model->materials[nummaterials].specular[0],
                            &model->materials[nummaterials].specular[1],
                            &model->materials[nummaterials].specular[2]);
                        break;
                    case 'a':
                        fscanf(file, "%f %f %f",
                            &model->materials[nummaterials].ambient[0],
                            &model->materials[nummaterials].ambient[1],
                            &model->materials[nummaterials].ambient[2]);
                        break;
                    default:
                        /* eat up rest of line */
                        fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 'd':       // PRL 20030806: dissolve factor, pseudo-transparency.
                fscanf(file, "%f", &model->materials[nummaterials].diffuse[3]);
                break;
#ifdef GLM_MATERIAL_TEXTURES
            case 'm':       // PRL 20030806: texturemap.
                if (strstr(buf, "map_Kd")) { // Process diffuse colour map.
                    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file);      // Read up to (and including) EOL from file into string.
                    buf[strlen(buf)-1] = '\0';          // nuke '\n'.
                    model->materials[nummaterials].texturemap = strdup(buf+1);  // Save relative path from mtl file. +1 skips leading space.
                    // Handle relative paths from model and material.
                    dir = glmDirName(filename);
                    model->materials[nummaterials].texturemappath = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(dir) + strlen(model->materials[nummaterials].texturemap) + 1));
                    strcpy(model->materials[nummaterials].texturemappath, dir);
                    strcat(model->materials[nummaterials].texturemappath, model->materials[nummaterials].texturemap);
                    free(dir);
                    if (readTexturesNow) {
                        if (!readTextureAndSendToGL(contextIndex, model->materials[nummaterials].texturemappath, &(model->materials[nummaterials].texturemap_index), &(model->materials[nummaterials].texturemap_hasAlpha), FALSE, model->flipTextureV)) {
                            EDEN_LOGe("glmReadMTL(): Error loading texture.\n");
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // Unsupported options:
                    // map_Ka, ambient colour map.
                    // map_Ks, specular colour map.
                    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file);      // eat up rest of line.
                }
                break;
#endif // GLM_MATERIAL_TEXTURES
            case 'i':       // Illumination model.
                fscanf(file, "%d", &model->materials[nummaterials].illum);
                break;
            default:
                /* eat up rest of line */
                fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file);
                break;
        }
    }
    free(filename);
    return (TRUE);
}

/* glmWriteMTL: write a wavefront material library file
 *
 * model   - properly initialized GLMmodel structure
 * modelpath  - pathname of the model being written
 * mtllibname - name of the material library to be written
 */
static GLvoid
glmWriteMTL(GLMmodel* model, char* modelpath, char* mtllibname)
{
    FILE* file;
    char* dir;
    char* filename;
    GLMmaterial* material;
    GLuint i;

    dir = glmDirName(modelpath);
    filename = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(dir)+strlen(mtllibname)));
    strcpy(filename, dir);
    strcat(filename, mtllibname);
    free(dir);

    /* open the file */
    file = fopen(filename, "w");
    if (!file) {
        EDEN_LOGe("glmWriteMTL() failed: can't open file \"%s\".\n",
            filename);
        exit(1);
    }
    free(filename);

    /* spit out a header */
    fprintf(file, "#  \n");
    fprintf(file, "#  Wavefront MTL generated by GLM library\n");
    fprintf(file, "#  \n");
    fprintf(file, "#  GLM library\n");
    fprintf(file, "#  Nate Robins\n");
    fprintf(file, "#  ndr@pobox.com\n");
    fprintf(file, "#  http://www.pobox.com/~ndr\n");
    fprintf(file, "#  \n\n");

    for (i = 0; i < model->nummaterials; i++) {
        material = &model->materials[i];
        fprintf(file, "newmtl %s\n", material->name);
        fprintf(file, "Ka %f %f %f\n", 
            material->ambient[0], material->ambient[1], material->ambient[2]);
        fprintf(file, "Kd %f %f %f\n", 
            material->diffuse[0], material->diffuse[1], material->diffuse[2]);
        fprintf(file, "Ks %f %f %f\n", 
            material->specular[0],material->specular[1],material->specular[2]);
        fprintf(file, "Ns %f\n", material->shininess / 128.0 * 1000.0);
        if (material->diffuse[3] != 1.0) fprintf(file, "d %f\n", material->diffuse[3]); // PRL 20030806: dissolve factor, pseudo-transparency.
#ifdef GLM_MATERIAL_TEXTURES
        if (material->texturemap) fprintf(file, "map_Kd %s\n", material->texturemap); // PRL 20030806: texturemap.
#endif // GLM_MATERIAL_TEXTURES
        fprintf(file, "illum %d\n", material->illum);
        fprintf(file, "\n");
    }
}

static void trim(char *buf)
{
    size_t index;

    if (!buf) return;

    index = strlen(buf);
    if (!index) return;
    index--;

    // Strip trailing CR and NL chars.
    while (index && (buf[index] == '\r' || buf[index] == '\n')) {
        buf[index] = '\0';
        index--;
    }
}


GLMmodel*
glmReadOBJ(const char *filename, const int contextIndex)
{
    return (glmReadOBJ3(filename, contextIndex, TRUE, FALSE));
}

GLMmodel*
glmReadOBJ2(const char *filename, const int contextIndex, const GLboolean readTexturesNow)
{
    return (glmReadOBJ3(filename, contextIndex, readTexturesNow, FALSE));
}

GLMmodel*
glmReadOBJ3(const char *filename, const int contextIndex, const GLboolean readTexturesNow, const GLboolean flipTextureV)
{
    GLMmodel* model;
    FILE*   file;

    /* open the file */
    file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!file) {
        EDEN_LOGe("glmReadOBJ() failed: can't open data file \"%s\".\n", filename);
        return (NULL);
    }

    /* allocate a new model */
    model = (GLMmodel*)malloc(sizeof(GLMmodel));
    model->pathname     = strdup(filename);
    model->mtllibname   = NULL;
    model->numvertices  = 0;
    model->vertices     = NULL;
    model->numnormals   = 0;
    model->normals      = NULL;
    model->numtexcoords = 0;
    model->texcoords    = NULL;
    model->numfacetnorms    = 0;
    model->facetnorms   = NULL;
    model->numtriangles = 0;
    model->triangles    = NULL;
    model->nummaterials = 0;
    model->materials    = NULL;
    model->numgroups    = 0;
    model->groups       = NULL;
    model->arrays       = NULL;
    model->arrayMode    = 0;
    model->readTextureRequired = !readTexturesNow;
    model->flipTextureV        = flipTextureV;

    /* make a first pass through the file to get a count of the number
    of vertices, normals, texcoords & triangles */
    glmFirstPass(model, file, contextIndex, readTexturesNow);

    /* allocate memory */
    model->vertices = (GLfloat*)malloc(sizeof(GLfloat) *
        3 * (model->numvertices + 1));          // Uses + 1 because vertices, normals and texcoords are numbered from 1, not 0.
    model->triangles = (GLMtriangle*)malloc(sizeof(GLMtriangle) *
        model->numtriangles);
    if (model->numnormals) {
        model->normals = (GLfloat*)malloc(sizeof(GLfloat) *
            3 * (model->numnormals + 1));       // Uses + 1 because vertices, normals and texcoords are numbered from 1, not 0.
    }
    if (model->numtexcoords) {
        model->texcoords = (GLfloat*)malloc(sizeof(GLfloat) *
            2 * (model->numtexcoords + 1));     // Uses + 1 because vertices, normals and texcoords are numbered from 1, not 0.
    }

    /* rewind to beginning of file and read in the data this pass */
    rewind(file);

    glmSecondPass(model, file);

    /* close the file */
    fclose(file);

    return model;
}
```

However , the following snippet works

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL JNIFUNCTION_DEMO(Initialise(JNIEnv* env, jobject object)) {



    for(int i=0;i<NUM_MODELS;i++){

            models[i].patternID=-1;
    //      models[i].transformationMatrix=PUT_SOME_PLACEHOLDER_TEMPORARY_VARIABLE_HERE;
            models[i].visible=false;
            models[i].obj=NULL;
            models[i].not_null=false;
         //mean they are null ...
    }
    const char *model1file = "Data/models/pinball/Ferrari_Modena_Spider.obj";
    models[0].patternID = arwAddMarker("nft;DataNFT/pinball");
    arwSetMarkerOptionBool(models[0].patternID, ARW_MARKER_OPTION_SQUARE_USE_CONT_POSE_ESTIMATION, false);
    arwSetMarkerOptionBool(models[0].patternID, ARW_MARKER_OPTION_FILTERED, true);

    models[0].obj = glmReadOBJ2(model1file, 0, 0); // context 0, don't read textures yet.
    if (!models[0].obj) {
        LOGE("Error loading model from file '%s'.", model1file);
        exit(-1);
    }
    glmScale(models[0].obj, 0.035f);
    //glmRotate(models[0].obj, 3.14159f / 2.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glmCreateArrays(models[0].obj, GLM_SMOOTH | GLM_MATERIAL | GLM_TEXTURE);
    models[0].visible = false;
    models[0].not_null = true;

    LOGE("trying to add a marker in Initialise");

}
```

The only difference seem to be , that in intialize , I have hardcoded the paths ....but in addMarkerandModel ...I am giving them as parameters passed through jni

Please help!!!!

Comment: Can you post more details about the error

Comment: Where are the logs?

Comment: It was a logical mistake on my side , I was sending the wrong address as parameter .. sorry for bothering others

Answer (score 1):

Reading a .obj file in ARToolKit's glm proceeds in a few steps. First, the .obj file is parsed, then any referenced .mtl files are loaded, and finally, if the .mtl file refers to a texture (only power-of-two size .sgi and JPEGs are supported in ARToolKit's glm reader) then those are lazily loaded once an OpenGL context is available.

If you're getting an error that the .mtl file can't be found, then it indicates that the first step is actually OK. glm was able to find and read the .obj file, but the .obj file referred to a .mtl file which couldn't be found.

Go through your .obj file(s) in a text editor, find all .mtl references, and edit them so that the correct relative path is referred to.

Comment: Thx , I got the error , it was that I was sending the wrong address as jstring...But your answers gives insight into how ARToolkit's glm reader parses the .obj and .mtl files , which I require at this point of time . So thanks.

Comment: also my approach in the code therefore works....so if anyone is viewing this answer , u can approach the problem stated like I have done above as my problem was something else!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to work with supper simple code first. Try to isolate the issue. Make sure that passed string is actually what you are looking for.

Here: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-009/

you can find supper simple sample code. Just the raw string processing.

Try to start with similar code in your case. Check whether passed value is really what you are looking for.